# pidof -x $0 returns 2 instead of expected 1, is there a one-line alternative?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In a bash script, I'm trying to use the following line to determine if another process is executing the current script:

`/sbin/pidof -x $0 |wc -w`

But the response is always 2, instead of the expected value of 1.

I've tried the following calls:
`/sbin/pidof -x $0` returns 1 pid
`/sbin/pidof -x $0 |wc -w` returns 2
`/sbin/pidof -x $0 |head` returns 2 pids
`/sbin/pidof -x $0 |head |wc -w` returns 2
`/sbin/pidof -x $0 |head |tail` returns 2 pids
`/sbin/pidof -x $0 |head |tail |wc -w` returns 2

Can anyone suggest an alternative (or fix) to achieve what I'm trying to do, and explain why piping the output to anything causes pidof output to go "a bit funny"?

---

This is how the script currently uses pidof, which works fine:

```
RUNNING=`/sbin/pidof -x $0`
RUNNING=`echo -n ${RUNNING} | wc -w`
[[ ${RUNNING} -gt 1 ]] && return
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only trying to prevent a second running script the following will do the trick:

```
pid=/tmp/$(basename $0).pid
[ -e $pid ] && exit 0;
trap 'rm -f $pid >/dev/null 2>&1;' 0
trap 'exit 2' 1 2 3 15
touch $pid
```

Just start your script with those lines. Basically it checks for a file and stop execution if the file is present. Note that if you kill (-9) the running script you are responsible for cleaning up the pid file that was created. Kill (-9) bypasses the shell trap that would otherwise clean up the pid file.

Comment: Yeah there's a bunch of alternatives using lock files etc, but I'm only interested in using live process checking for simplicity. pidof does do the job, but I'm trying to understand why it behaves the way it does.